# javascript timing with php

Tags: php, javascript, timing

i'm trying to execute a javascript function every 'n'  periods of time ,the function will call a php file which will execute a sort of code,but unfortunately it doesn't work ,here;s the code

```
<p id="code"></p>

    <script>
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){showUser()},1000);



    function showUser() {
        var xmlhttp = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getuser.php');
        xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("code").innerHTML=t;

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't exactly help us figure out what the problem is. Do you REALLY want to be hammering your server with an ajax request every second? And any reason you're rolling your own ajax code instead of using something like jquery?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work."  Is this code executing?  Is it making the AJAX request?  Is it receiving the expected response?

Comment: What is this `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;`? It seems that `t` is not defined. It may cause an exception on your code and it will not work.

Comment: What errors show up in your browser console?

Comment: BTW, I can see you're an old school developer so here go a old school tip: the `xmlHttp.open` function have be called before the bind of the `onreadystatechange` or it will not work on IE6 and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//edit this

document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

//to

document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;


//and delete

document.getElementById("code").innerHTML=t;
```

Comment: also keep check the timing of return from php via firebug and adjust accordingly. 1 sec is quite fast.